# How to fetch a value of key from localStorage and put it to input by hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Sorry, I've only started learn hooks.
I can't correctly write it: on page load, must be fetched from localStorage a value of key appData and puts it in the input.

```
import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [appData, setValue] = useState('');
  
  useEffect(() => localStorage.setItem('appData', appData), [appData]);
 
  return (
    <div>
      React Marathon, appData: <input size='5' defaultValue={appData}></input>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
export default function App() {  
  const [appData, setValue] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!localStorage.getItem('appData')) {
      localStorage.setItem('appData', appData)
    }
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => setValue(localStorage.getItem('appData')), []);

  return (
    <div>
      React Marathon, appData: <input size='5' defaultValue={appData}></input>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

Just set the initial value to the localStorage value

```
const [appData, setValue] = useState(localStorage.getItem('appData') || '')
```

Comment: i tried it, but it didn't work. Maybe, i made some mistakes earlier. I'll try now again! Thanks you!:)

Comment: it doesn't work! Sorry!:( Tests write:  fail - the "input" should have value from localStorage

Comment: your edited variant doesn't work too. I tried it earlier. An now tried again - the same fail in tests.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jb9pqct6/ - it works

Comment: sorry, but in my situation it must pass test, and it fail them.

Comment: Well then it's testing something else.  I don't know what to tell you.  If I had to guess, you either aren't understanding the requirements correctly or aren't communicating them correctly, and you *also* want to set `appData` to whatever they input, and need to also do `<input size='5' defaultValue={appData} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}></input>`

Comment: i tried this with `<input size='5' value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}></input>` and it didn't work. Now, i understand, that it's oncorrect. Thank you - will try your variant now

Comment: this variant doesn't work too.

Comment: 'There is the functional component App which renders one element div with text React Marathon in it. Using hooks write code to provide next functionality: on page load, the component App fetches from localStorage a value of key appData and puts it in the input'

Comment: Add  timeout time to your tests, may be that will solve the problem

Comment: @dave, 
'Test suite for item "hook-effect" › test getting data form localStorage › the "input" should have value from localStorage 
 TypeError: localStorage.setItem is not a function'

Comment: @dave, when i wrote function useState it too didn't work